# Calculating two different means In R

Tags: r, mean

I am trying to calculate two different means from the following datasets in 'R'

```
Plot   Date     Time Canopyheight     mean    pre       post    Diff
103B1 11/12/2019 1    50
103B1 11/12/2019 4    50
103B1 11/12/2019 6    78
103B1 11/12/2019 22   100            69.5
103B1 11/13/2019 1     60
103B1 11/13/2019 4     70
103B1 11/13/2019 6     80 
103B1 11/13/2019 22   100            77.5     73.5
103B1 11/14/2019 1    50
103B1 11/14/2019 4    50
103B1 11/14/2019 6    78
103B1 11/14/2019 22  100            69.5
103B1 11/15/2019 1    60
103B1 11/15/2019 4    80
103B1 11/15/2019 6    90
103B1 11/15/2019 22  120            87.5               78.5     5.0
```

I am able to get the mean value but I am not able to get pre and post value.

**The expected Result**

Using the code, we should be able to get the value of '73.5' which is the average of '69.5 and 77.5', and other values are calculated as such. The difference will be calculated as the difference between the Pre and Post value.

**The code**

```
Prepost <- Prepost %>% group_by(Plot, Date) %>% 
  mutate(meancanopyheight = mean(Canopyheight, na.rm = T))
Prepost$Preharvest <- lapply(Prepost$Date, function(m) mean(Prepost$meanCanopyheight[Prepost$Date >= m |Prepost$Date <= m+4| Prepost$Date == m+8], na.rm = TRUE))
```

I tried to calculate but I am not able to calculate, I have added the code here for all of your references.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(Canopyheight)) %>%
  mutate(group = rep(c("pre", "post"), each = 2)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(mean))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   group  mean
#>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 post   78.5
#> 2 pre    73.5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Based on further data from the OP to make this solution more general:

```r
library(dplyr)


df <- structure(list(Plot = c("TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", 
"TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", 
"TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", 
"TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", 
"TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", 
"TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", 
"TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", "TF_103B1", 
"TF_103B1", "TF_103B1"), Date = structure(c(18217, 18217, 18217, 
18217, 18218, 18218, 18218, 18218, 18219, 18219, 18219, 18219, 
18220, 18221, 18221, 18221, 18221, 18222, 18222, 18222, 18222, 
18246, 18246, 18246, 18246, 18247, 18247, 18247, 18247, 18248, 
18248, 18248, 18248, 18249, 18250, 18250, 18250, 18250, 18251, 
18251, 18251, 18251), class = "Date"), Time = c("1", "4", "6", 
"22", "1", "4", "6", "22", "1", "4", "6", "22", "22", "1", "4", 
"6", "22", "1", "4", "6", "22", "1", "4", "6", "22", "1", "4", 
"6", "22", "1", "4", "6", "22", "22", "1", "4", "6", "22", "1", 
"4", "6", "22"), Canopyheight = c(2064.55, 2064.51, 2063.03, 
2063.62, 2065.94, 2064.83, 2061.58, 2064.07, 2066.97, 2063.99, 
2065.37, 2064.7, 2067.8, 2065.6, 2067.05, 2064.95, 2075.76, 2073.06, 
2079.23, 2072.75, 2068.81, 2065.66, 2065.85, 2065.65, 2063.65, 
2063.44, 2068.05, 2072.38, 2067.2, 2068.1, 2067.26, 2069.27, 
2063.05, 2088.45, 2086.24, 2088.91, 2092.04, 2092, 2092.67, 2090.7, 
2091.59, 2090.99)), row.names = c(NA, 42L), class = "data.frame")

  df <- df   %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(Canopyheight)) %>%
  mutate(prepost = rep(rep(c("pre", "post"), each = 3), length.out = n()))

  df$start_date <- rep(df$Date[seq(nrow(df)) %% 6 == 0], each = 6)

  df %>%
  group_by(start_date, prepost) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(mean))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   start_date [2]
#>   start_date prepost  mean
#>   <date>     <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 2019-11-22 post    2070.
#> 2 2019-11-22 pre     2064.
#> 3 2019-12-21 post    2090.
#> 4 2019-12-21 pre     2067.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used in my data and I am getting this error " Column `group` must be length 18 (the number of rows) or one, not 2". Any ideas of why I am getting it.

Comment: Ah, yes @SonisaSharma it must be because you have 18 different dates in your data rather than just 2. You could change `each  = 2` to `each = 18`. You probably want a more robust way of changing it. This would require you to assign a grouping variable that logically unites the matching "pre" and "post" measurements.

Comment: Thanks, Allan and I tried that too and I still get the same message.

Comment: @SonisaSharma I take it you can get as far as `summarize(mean = mean(CanopyHeight))` ? How many rows does that output?

Comment: I have 846 rows

Comment: @SonisaSharma and are these all the alternating means for "pre" and "post"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208260/discussion-between-sonisa-sharma-and-allan-cameron).

Comment: Thanks so much Allan for your help.